# Shared Core Data Fetch Requests in Swift 3

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3

Below is my fetch request, adapted to Swift 3 to build without errors. I have very similar fetch operations in a 5-10 other places in my app but for different entities, added sort descriptors, and predicates.

My original understanding of Core Data wasn't great. I watched the WWDC Core Data talk on how Swift 3 changed some context and fetch rules.

My question is, thanks to Swift 3, can I now shorten this or cut out some part of it to share with other fetches? Or maybe even now get rid of calling new contexts again and again and just do it once at the start of the app?

```
func coreDataCall (statToSave: Int) {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Stats", in: managedContext)
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Stats")
    do {
        let fetchedResults = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as? [NSManagedObject]
        if let results = fetchedResults {
            newContext = results
        }
    } catch { 
        print(error)  
    }
    let task = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: managedContext)
    let lastUsed = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 7, to: nextDayChange)
    task.setValue(lastUsed, forKey: "date")
    task.setValue(statToSave, forKey: "percentComp")
    newContext.insert(task, at: 0)
    do {
        try managedContext.save()
    } catch _ {
        print("Stat did not save.")
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello! Did you mean the ManagedObjectContext?

Comment: Swift 3 for the Core Data! It's a great combination ever before.